# How to multiple data column in a oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there are two columns from different table

```
T1      T2
====    ====
1       A
2       B
3       C
====    ====
```

I am trying to have a query result like this

```
T3      T2
============
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       B
2       C
3       A
3       B
3       C
====    ====
```

The sequence does not matter but just need combination of every record from both column in the result. Is there any API can do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a `cartesian product`.  You can use a `cross join` for that:

```
select t1.field, t2.field 
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2
```